# Formula to add X months to a date?

Tags: spreadsheet, date, iwork-numbers

How can I add X months to an existing date in iWork Numbers?

Comment: I don't believe there is one; at least, not one that is truly correct. For insight into why not, read http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

=EDATE(start_date,months_after_start_date)

Start_Date can be a cell or a specific date.
The number after the comma is the number of additional months.

For example, if 7/15/17 is in Cell A1 and you want Cell B1 to read 8/15/17 then you would use the formula: =EDATE(A1,1)

Comment: ah - cool & thanks. Hacked it with 'start date me+(365*(2))' but EDATE is obviously better. Dc